# TimeoutException thrown consuming WCF Service hosted in the Network

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I'm writing a web application that will be hosted in Electron on a Raspberry PI. The Raspberry PI has a fingerprint scanner attached which returns me a string that I need to check if the fingerprint is registered in my Database on another server. I'm doing this by invoking a WCF Service Method hosted on the network.
Now the problem is when calling the WCF Service I get a timeout after 1 Minute (default timeout) but it works when I'm running the application on my local machine.

Service Code:

```cs
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://192.168.0.154:8733/GlauxSoft.SnackBox.WebService/")]
public interface IService
{
        [OperationContract]
        Fingerprint GetFingerprintByUniqueId(string uniqueId);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public Fingerprint GetFingerprintByUniqueId(string uniqueId)
    {
        // This is just a DataBase call, nothing extraordinarily expensive
        using (EvidenceSessionHelper.CreateDefaultWebServiceSession())
        {
            return Fingerprint.MapAuthentifizierungToWebServiceFingerprint(QueryAuthentifizierung.GetFingerprintByUniqueId(uniqueId));
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer Code:

```cs
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://192.168.0.154:8733/GlauxSoft.SnackBox.WebService/", ConfigurationName = "ISnackBoxService")]
public interface ISnackBoxService
{
    [OperationContract(
        Action ="http://192.168.0.154:8733/GlauxSoft.SnackBox.WebService/IService/GetFingerprintByUniqueId", 
        ReplyAction = "http://192.168.0.154:8733/GlauxSoft.SnackBox.WebService/IService/GetFingerprintByUniqueIdResponse")]
    Fingerprint GetFingerprintByUniqueId(string uniqueId);
}

public class ServiceClient : ClientBase<IService>, IService
{
    public SnackBoxServiceClient() : 
            base(GetDefaultBinding(), GetDefaultEndpointAddress())
    {
        Endpoint.Name = EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISnackBoxService.ToString();
    }

    public enum EndpointConfiguration
    {
        BasicHttpBinding_ISnackBoxService
    }

    public Fingerprint GetFingerprintByUniqueId(string uniqueId)
    {
        return Channel.GetFingerprintByUniqueId(uniqueId);
    }
}
```

The consumer is a ASP.NET Razor app written in .NET Core 3 Preview 5

And I'm calling the Consumer code like so:

```cs
var service = new ServiceClient();
var evdFingerprint = service.GetFingerprintByUniqueId("Test String"); // <-- Runs for 1 minute and throws the TimeoutException
```

Here is the stack trace:

> System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to 'http://192.168.0.154:8733/GlauxSoft.SnackBox.WebService/' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync(Message message, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsync(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)

**Edit:** I've done some further testing, it seems like any HTTP request to my local machine isn't getting through as doing `wget 192.168.0.154:5106 -o index.html` and monitoring my network traffic with wireshark isn't showing me any GET requests to my pc and going to `https://192.168.0.154:5106` times out as well.
I am however able to ping my local pc and I can even SSH into my Raspberry PI and I can also establish a VNC Remote Desktop session with my Raspberry PI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was simple enough, I needed to use HTTPS, so instead of connecting to `http://192.168.0.154:8733/...`
I needed to connect to `https://192.168.0.154:8733/...`

Answer (score 0):

you can configure time out in many ways on your binding .In Code,

```
    WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
    binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
    binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

or in web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding openTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't want to increase the timeout (as having to wait up to 10 minutes for my authentication server to respond is ludicrous)

Answer (score 0):

> GetDefaultBinding(), GetDefaultEndpointAddress()

I would like that you could share more details related to above method body with me.
What is the ClientCredentailType of the default binding? since some bindings are not well compatible with Core(WS-* binding). Also, have you modified the service endpoint address on the client side when you call the service from another machine?
In my opinion, we could use the Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider tool to generate the client proxy, then modify the service endpoint address and provide a client credential explicitly depending on the binding configuration on the server side.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: The `GetDefaultBinding` and `GetDefaultEndpointAddress` methods both return the correct IP Address (192.168.0.154), I generated the code via the "Add connected service" dialog option in Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Preview 3, could go into detail on how I could provide client credentials explicitly?

Comment: Since the binding element we use to create the secure channel can authenticate the client, the configuration of the binding might require the client to provide a credential. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-specify-the-client-credential-type
for example, WsHttpBinding requires the client to provide a windows credential (the account of the server) by default.